# 'module' object has no attribute 'sim_pearson'

Tags: python, python-2.4

```py
critics = {'Lisa Rose': {'Lady in the Water': 2.5, 'Snakes on a plane': 3.5, 'Just My Luck': 3.0,

'Superman Returns': 3.5, 'You, Me and Dupree': 2.5, 'The Night Listener': 3.0},

'Toby':{'Snakes on a Plane': 4.5, 'You, me and Dupreee': 1.0},

'Gene Seymour':{'Lady in the Water':3.0, 'Snakes on a plane': 3.5,'Just My Luck': 1.5,
    'Superman Returns': 5.0,'You, Me and Dupree': 3.5, 'The Night Listener': 3.0}}

from math import sqrt

def sim_distance(person1, person2):
    si={}
    for item in prefs[person1]:
        if item in prefs[person2]:
            si[item]=1


    if len[si]== 0: return 0


    sum_of_squares=sum([pow[prefs[person1][item]-prefs[person2][item],2]
                        for item in prefes[person1] if item in prefs[person2]])
    return 1/(1+sqrt(sum_of_squares))
```

---

```
>> import recommendations
>>recommendations.sim_distance(recommendations.critics, 'Lisa Rose', 'Gene Seymour')
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line1, in?
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'sim_pearson'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the above code is in single file .

using command line:

1.open the command line

2.change the directory to the location where your python code is( use cd C:\user\Python27 or whatever your location is)

3.type python hit enter(it will start the console for python)

4.now type the following and hit enter after each line

> > > from recommendations import critics
> > >
> > > from recommendations import sim_distance
> > >
> > > sim_distance(critics,'Lisa Rose','Gene Seymour')

Hope this will help to run your code